# 1D kernel estimation to compare PDF ratios: how to set tails?

Tags: r, statistics, kernel-density, probability-density, density-plot

Trying to create 1D kernels from data observations (weekly time points). I have been using the `density()` function from the `stats` R package. I am doing this so I can take the ratio of a treatment's pdf and the control pdf along the x-axis, and then perform permutation tests with it.

Long story short, I know in my observations that at weeks 4 and 16 (the to and from values in the function), that there is no observations. Yet, my tails often go beyond these points.

From a statistical standpoint, I am not sure how to "force" the function to estimate the pdf with 0s at these points. Having 0s at the correct points (and same between all treatments) is critical for me being able to do the downstream analysis.

I have played around the `bw`, `adjust`, `n`, and `to/from` parameters, and also attempted to manually set the density values to 0 at known ends. I'm just not sure what to do from here, but I know I'm doing something very naive...

An example of the code I have is:

```
common_x = seq(4,16,by=0.02)

pdf_ctrl = density(control$week, bw=0.7, from=min(common_x),to=max(common_x), n=500)
pdf1 = density(treatment1$week, bw=0.7, from=min(common_x),to=max(common_x), n=500)
```

Then take the ratios at each point of x (since they have the same common x values)

Not sure if a better question for the stats exchange...unclear if I have a statistics problem or an R code issue.

No dummy code since it's so straightforward, but below is a plot example of what I am talking about, and happy to provide more code/data if helpful.

[image: example estimated pdf]

Comment: I think you are just running up against one of the limits of kernel density estimates. Essentially they plot a little Gaussian bell curve at each observation, add all those bell curves up, then normalise the result so that the area under the curve is 1. You can change the shape of the kernel using the `kernel` argument, or narrow the bandwidth down, but if you want a nice smooth density curve then "tails" are an unavoidable side effect. What's wrong with limiting the x values to the range of your data? Or perhaps a histogram would be better?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Allan. I think I misspoke, I am fine with tails. In fact, I’m doing this analysis to GENERATE tails so I can assess if the tails between the two distributions are different or not. The problem I am running into is that the rails don’t actually go to 0? And they don’t go to 0 by when I know from observations that they should be 0. 

I might be fundamentally misunderstanding something though…

Comment: Yes, if you have some counts at x = 5 but none at x = 4, then the bell curves centred at x = 5 effectively sum up to a bell curve that spills over onto x = 4 (and x = 6), so they will be non-zero there. The fact that there are no observations at x = 4 just means no bell curves are placed there. The density function makes no attempt to force the density to zero there; the value at x = 4 is just the sum of the tails of any adjacent bell curves. If you don't understand, I guess I could try to show this graphically in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand why the density is not at zero even though you know the counts are zero at a certain point, you need to understand how a 1-D kernel estimate is generated.

Essentially, `density` places a kernel at each point on the x axis where you have data. By default, this kernel is a normal distribution, with a standard deviation controlled by the `bw` parameter.

The height of the kernel at each point is scaled by the total number of data points, so that if you have 100 data points, the bell curve will be 1/100 the height of a normal distribution.

`density` then adds all those bell curves up, giving the final result.

Let's take a short vector of integers spread between 5 and 15 to demonstrate:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c(5, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 
                       10, 10, 11, 11, 13, 13, 14, 15))
```

Now let's plot the density curve of this vector:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dens <- density(df$x)

p <- ggplot(as.data.frame(dens[c("x", "y")]), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 4, linetype = 2) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:20)  +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.15), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  guides(fill = "none")

p
```

[image]

Note that even though we had no values at x = 4, the density is not 0 here.

To find out why, let us recreate the algorithm that `density` uses. We will get a little normal distribution at each point where we have data. The heights are scaled according to the count at each point:

```r
df2 <- df %>% 
  reframe(xval = seq(0, 20, 0.1),
          y = dnorm(seq(0, 20, 0.1), first(x), bw.nrd0(df$x)) * n()/nrow(df), 
          .by = x)

p + geom_area(aes(x = xval, fill = factor(x)), 
              data = df2, position = "identity")
```

[image]

Notice that if we stack all these bell curves on top of each other we get our kernel density estimate:

```r
p + geom_area(aes(x = xval, fill = factor(x)), data = df2, position = "stack")
```

[image]

We can see immediately that the reason for the non-zero density at x = 4 is that the kernel at x = 5 has "spilled over" onto 4. In theory, we could simply narrow the bandwidth so that this doesn't happen:

```r
plot(density(df$x, bw = 0.3))
```

[image]

But now of course we have a new problem: our nice smooth density kernel looks very spikey and is no longer smooth.

So the size of the tails is inextricably linked to how smooth your density is. If you want the tail to hit zero at 4, you need a lower bandwidth, but then you have a lumpy density plot. If you want a smooth density plot, you can't expect it to magically tail off where your counts are 0. If you manually flatten the tails pist-hoc, then the area under the density curve is no longer 1 and therefore it is not a true p.d.f unless you manually normalize it.

Of course the purists here would point out that a simple plot of counts would be best here; simple, complete, no assumptions and no wasted ink:

```r
 plot(table(df$x))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for this extremely thorough answer! That definitely makes sense- a lot of that I had figured from reading but wasn’t sure if it was correct. This is phenomenal, and I greatly appreciate the visuals as well.

Would you have any additional suggestions/cautions when considering creating the PDFs for comparison? I have the common x axis, bw, and n, just not sure if I need something else!

Answer (score 3):

I would use the **kde1d** package.

```r
library(kde1d)

x <- seq(4, 16, by = 0.02)

y <- 4 + 12*rbeta(100, 5, 7)

fit <- kde1d(y, xmin = 4, xmax = 16)

# estimated density evaluated at x
dkde1d(x, fit)
```

If a value of `x` is outside `[xmin, xmax]`, `dkde1d(x, fit)` returns 0 for this value.